# Castle.Windsor: passing a dependency through 2 typed factories

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor, typed-factory-facility

**Types:**

```
public interface IWidgetFactoryFactory { IWidgetFactory CreateFactory(); } 

public interface IWidgetFactory { FooWidget CreateFoo(Foo model); }

public class FooWidget(IContextualService service, Foo model) { }
```

**Registration:**

```
Component.For<IWidgetFactoryFactory>()
         .AsFactory(),

// the CustomFactoryComponentSelector is unnecessary for this discussion, just know 
// it's there
Component.For<IWidgetFactory>()
         .AsFactory(c => c.SelectedWith<CustomFactoryComponentSelector>()),
```

**Question:**

What I want is to be able to add a method to `IWidgetFactoryFactory` which would take an `IContextualService`:

```
IWidgetFactory CreateFactory(IContextualService service);
```

and then create the factory proxy such that when I call `IWidgetFactory.CreateFoo` it resolves the `IContextualService` dependency from that parameter passed via the new `CreateFactory` method.

Note that I will be creating and calling multiple `IWidgetFactoryFactory.CreateFactory(IContextualService)` in different contexts, and I want each `IContextualService` to reflect the context it is called in and passed from.

Are there any ideas on how could this be done?

*Update:*
There is a [related thread](http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-devel/browse_thread/thread/b1d850b4420af92a) on Castle-Dev mailing list on this issue.